# How can I get the confidence scores of LPRNet?

Tags: python, openvino, lpr, ctc

I am a newbie working on the LPRNet provided by openvino toolkit:
https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/training_extensions

I want to get the probability of the predicted result but it seems that `tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder` only returns `neg_sum_logits` and I'm not sure how to convert it into prabability.

Does anyone know how can I get that?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the validation app.
Inference Engine Validation Application is a tool that allows to infer deep learning models with standard inputs and outputs configuration and to collect simple validation metrics for topologies. It supports top-1 and top-5 metric for Classification networks and 11-points mAP metric for Object Detection networks.

You may refer here for some insight: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2019_R1/_inference_engine_samples_validation_app_README.html

And also this is a step by step explainations for the application of validation app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WAQSx3LC-M